# Android : GridLayout Highlight A Row

Tags: android, highlight, selected, android-gridlayout

I am writing a feedback screen for my app and using grid layout for it. 
 It is a static form which shows and image and text description.
I want to highlight the selected item so user is aware of the click event.
 While `listSelector` to set a background drawable was not available for gridlayout; `refNowTxt.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.frame_background))` did not highlight the entire row. 
I am thinking on retrieving the selected row and setting a background to highlight. 
 Appreciate any help on this.
Following is my layout.xml:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="7"
    android:paddingTop="6dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgWriteFeedback"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:src="@drawable/write_to_us"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblWriteFeedback"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/write_to_us"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@color/frame_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgRateUs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:src="@drawable/rate_us_resized"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblRateUs"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:text="@string/rate_us"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@color/frame_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgShareApp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:src="@drawable/share_resized"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblShareApp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:text="@string/share_app"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@color/frame_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"/>

</GridLayout>
```

` [image]

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27597199/3593066

Answer (score 0):

```
Inside adapter create a method,
private selectedIndex;
public void selectedIndex(int gridSelectionPosition)
{
 this.selectedIndex=gridSelectionPosition;
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}

and then inside getView method

Do something like this, 

 getView()
{
if(position==selectedIndex)
{
   view.setBackgroundColor(color);

}
else
{
  view.setBackgroundColor(white);
}

inside your gridview.OnItemClickListener

adapter.selectedIndex(position);
```

Comment: Thank. Attached the layout code. Not using adapter in my case.

Comment: Inside grid OnclickListener set View.setBackgroundColor(Color) try this dude. or android:listselector="@color/yourcolor". you can also follow the link Mustaneer answer. you can use android:listSelector which is available for gridview to.. please check on that.

Comment: `GridLayout coreLayout = (GridLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.settingsGrid);
        coreLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("Settings Fragment","Grid View Item Clicked:"+view.getId());
            }
        });` does not get called in this case.

Comment: Hi, there is no GridView component in my code; GridLayout does not have setOnItemClickListener method. The layout xml has GridLayout and then views that are setup in a static manner.

Comment: gridLayout, sorry buddy , out of ideas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96640/discussion-between-allzhere-and-hourglass).